# Defining relationships in NodeEntity vs RelationshipEntity

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am new to Neo4j, and am going through Spring-data-Neo4j documentation. Currently I am not clear about defining the node relationships within the entity beans.

We can have `@Relationship` on a property, with `direction` as `INCOMING` or `OUTGOING`. Also we can have `@RelationshipEntity` to define `@StartNode` and `@EndNode`. 
`@RelationshipEntity` is required if we have additional properties on the relationship. But once we define a Relationship entity do we still need `@Relationship` on either nodes in the relation? Do we need to define all relationships in Entity class on both side? How to decide? Do defining all relationships on both sides affect the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using relationship entities, the current release of SDN 4 requires you to reference it from *at least* the start node entity.

You should also reference it from the end node entity if you plan to persist the end node entity and expect the relationship entity to be persisted as well.

The recommendation is to have your object model represented as closely as possible to your graph model. Examples and more explanation at http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/09/03/sdn-4-object-model.html

Note that if you have no properties on the relationship, then you must not use a RelationshipEntity and instead use regular `@Relationship`s

Comment: how do we handle many to many relationship? should the start node contain the `Set` of `RelationshipEntity`? any example? Currently I am not able to save any `RelationshipEntity`

Comment: A relationship can connect only two nodes in the graph. So if you have a many-many such as a person belongs to many groups and groups contain many people, then you'd have a Set/List/Array of groups on the person entity, and a similar collection of persons on the group entity. Hope that helps.